# Always the same thread is put on waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

i have a problem with this simple exercise:
There is a parking area, that allows max 4 cars at a time and there are 6 cars.

The problem is that after 4 cars have entered, the next 2 cars go in waiting state and never enter.

Here is what i get on the screen:

```
Car 1 in
Car 2 in
Car 5 in
Car 6 in
Car 4 is waiting
Car 3 is waiting
Car 1 out
Car 1 in
Car 3 is waiting
Car 4 is waiting
Car 5 out
Car 5 in
Car 2 out
Car 2 in
and so on..
```

Here the classes:

```
public class Car extends Thread{

    int idCar;
    Monitor monitor;

    public Car(int id, Monitor monitor){
        idCar=id;
        this.monitor=monitor;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            monitor.enter(idCar);
            try{
               sleep(2000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            monitor.exit(idCar);
        }
    }

}

public class Monitor {

    int maxSpots;
    int parkedCars;

    public Monitor(int maxSpots){
        this.maxSpots=maxSpots;
        parkedCars=0;
    }

    public synchronized void enter(int idCar){
        while(parkedCars==maxSpots){
            try{
                System.out.println("Car "+idCar+" is waiting");
                wait();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        ++parkedCars;
        System.out.println("Car "+idCar+" in");
        notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized void exit(int idCar){
        /*while(parkedCars==0){   // i'm not sure if this check is needed, because
            try{              // no car will ever get out, if it's not in.
                wait();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }*/
        --parkedCars;
        System.out.println("Car "+idCar+" out");
        notifyAll();

    }

}

public class Parking {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Monitor m = new Monitor(4);

        Car c1 = new Car(1, m);
        Car c2 = new Car(2, m);
        Car c3 = new Car(3, m);
        Car c4 = new Car(4, m);
        Car c5 = new Car(5, m);
        Car c6 = new Car(6, m);

        c1.start();
        c2.start();
        c3.start();
        c4.start();
        c5.start();
        c6.start();

    }
}
```

Could anyone explain please?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have on your system?

Comment: The decision to assign `CPU` time to a `thread` is totally dependent on `JVM` `Thread Scheduler`. And the `algorithm` varies from platform to platform . We can't be ascertain of the sequence in which `threads` are going to hold the `lock` . In your system it might be same two cars going into `WAITING` state but on other system the cars in `WAITING` state keeps on changing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You designed your code so that your monitor **is not fair**. 
If a `Car` exits the slot it enters the next step in the loop, thus it tries to enter again instantly. In the meantime your other waiting `Car`s get woken up by `Thread.notifyAll()`.
Well, those `Thread`s aren't the fastest. They are not guaranteed to start working without a delay...

What happens to your `Car`, that just exited the slot? It tries to park in again. And as its thread hasn't waited it doesn't need to get back to work again... it parks in instantly.
What you might want is a **queue**. Add your requesting `Car` to a `Queue` and if an enter happens, notify your longest waiting `Car` first. Another approach, as Jan suggested, would be to **let those exiting `Car`s wait a bit** to give other parkers a chance. This could be achieved via using `Thread.yield()` or `Thread.sleep()` on the exiting `Car` (after it`s done with exiting).

This scenario you produced is quite annoying for all parties concerned. The honest waiting `Car`s are waiting for ever for their slot and the ego-parkers never get back home ;)

Comment: or maybe let each car wait some time (enough for its thread to yield) before it tries to repark. Normally a car does't leave a parking slot just to return immediately.

Comment: `Thread.yield()` would be enough, `Thread.sleep()` is also an option. I will add that.

Comment: Since a car always stays parked for two seconds (circa), it should stay unparked for two seconds as well.

Comment: oh well buddy, life isn't fair! :p  that's what my mom would say.

Comment: thanks all. i've added a 2 seconds sleep after the exit() and now it works "fine" :) I'm gonna add the queue to make it more realistic and one day i'll solve the parking problem! ;)